# how to validate two statements using IIf in vb code

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB and my task is to compare two statements. Please find the below piece of code:

```
Dim obj As Object = TryCast(mBindingSource.Current,DataRowView).Item("Emp_Status")
Dim ProcessEmp As eProcessEmp = IIf((mEmployee.IsTrue And (obj = eEmp_Status.Active Or obj = eEmp_Status.InActive)), eProcessEmp.SAVE, eProcessEmp.SUBMIT)
```

To this above code when `mEmployee.IsFalse` I should have like:

```
Dim ProcessEmp As eProcessEmp = IIf((mEmployee.IsFalse, eProcessEmp.Submit, eProcessEmp.Save)
```

How do I merge these two statements into single validation. Can someone please help?

Comment: This doesn't answer you question, but you have a potential pitfall in your code.  Are `Submit` and `Save` methods?  Or are they properties?  The `IIF` function will evaluate _both_ arguments so if they are methods, then both of them will be called.  `IIF` should not be used anymore.  Instead use the `IF` operator which has been added to VB.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic seems to be a bit faulty at the moment.

You first `IIF` has this logic:

```
IIf(
    (mEmployee.IsTrue And (obj = eEmp_Status.Active Or obj = eEmp_Status.InActive)),
    eProcessEmp.SAVE,
    eProcessEmp.SUBMIT
)
```

And your second one, if we flip `mEmployee.IsFalse` to `mEmployee.IsTrue` has this logic:

```
IIf(
    mEmployee.IsTrue,
    eProcessEmp.Save,
    eProcessEmp.Submit
)
```

Which basically means that you're ignoring the `(obj = eEmp_Status.Active Or obj = eEmp_Status.InActive)` condition in the first part of your logic.

But, if you want to be pedantic, this your combined logic is:

```
Dim ProcessEmp As eProcessEmp = IIf( _
    (Not mEmployee.IsFalse) Or _
        (mEmployee.IsTrue And _
            (obj = eEmp_Status.Active Or obj = eEmp_Status.InActive)), _
    eProcessEmp.SAVE, _
    eProcessEmp.SUBMIT)
```

But, again, that entire condition reduces down to `mEmployee.IsTrue` - so something is wrong with your logic.

Comment: Anybody will comment in him own answer that the proper equivalent in VB.Net is `IF` because `IIF` just a thing from the past decade that still exists for compatibility?.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - I agree, but using `IF` instead of `IIF` can be a breaking change. I just go with what the OP used unless it directly affects the answer.